# Webpack not detecting new modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

So I have a React app that I'm working on, I'm building the app with Visual Studio (ASP.NET Web API 2.0 for the backend). I had to make some pretty major changes to the app so I created a separate branch for it. I added a few JSX files to the project in the new branch and when I try to `require` them in a file like so:

```
const Reports = require("./Reports/Reports.jsx");
```

I get an error: "Uncaught Error: Cannot find Module ./Reports/Reports.jsx" in the web browser

It seems like webpack isn't detecting any of the newly added files on the branch, what could be the cause of this?

Here's my webpack config:

```
function getWebpackConfig(moreProps) {
var config = {
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        main: './src/start.jsx'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx$|\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.less$/,
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader!less-loader"
        }]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "~": path.resolve("./src")
        },
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    }
};

config = Object.assign({}, config, moreProps);

return config;
}
```

Here's my package.json containing the node_modules installed in the directory of my project:

```
    {
    "name": "internal auditing site",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Web Client for internal auditing site",
    "repository": "~company name excluded for StackOverflow~",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "lodash": "^4.11.1",
    "moment": "^2.12.0",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^15.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.4",
    "redux": "^3.4.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.0.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^0.11.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.7.6",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.6.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.4",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "history": "^2.0.1",
    "less": "^2.7.1",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
    "object-assign": "^4.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
     }
    }
```

I'm also not entirely sure if this is an issue with Webpack or Team Foundation Server.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your webpack config other than what you may be adding in with `moreProps`.

Comment: Are you exporting Reports.jsx correctly? have you tried restarting webpack?

Comment: @BradBumbalough I export Reports.jsx with `module.exports = Reports` after creating the reports object. The weird thing is all of my other modules work fine it's just the ones that I've newly added that are giving me problems. For instance I have a Root.jsx file that gets imported one line before Reports.jsx and it resolves just fine. Very strange. I actually build the webpack file via a gulp task, I'll post the entire Gulp File below.

Comment: @wrleskovec I'm starting to think that it's an issue with TFS, moreProps currently doesn't do anything it's just an empty object.

Comment: Yeah it's hard to say... I would ensure that you see the file in your normal file explorer, that the server is running from the right folder (not some other dupe location you may have cloned), and that the relative path is correct from where you're calling it.

Comment: @JoshSiegl, Why do you think your issue is TFS related? I can't see it's related to TFS.

Comment: Did you check the relative path of the file to make sure it is correct?